# curl request not able to concatenate strings

Tags: php, curl, concatenation

```
        $userid= '1' ;
        $conid='21' ;
        $lid= '139';
        $key = 'outcome';
        $values = 'yes,no';
        $bools= 'false';
        $datefrom= '2018-01-01';
        $dateto = '2018-01-01' ;
$ch = curl_init('https://api.call.com/get_field_response_count?userid='.$userid.'&conid='.$conid.'&lid='.$lid.'&key='.$key.'&values='.$values.'&bools='.$bools.'&datefrom='.$datefrom.'&dateto='.$dateto.'');


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

when i try this from postman i get results but when i try them form a php script using variables i dont get a result i think i figured that it has something to do with the way m sending my variables

Comment: @riggsfolly how is it the same :?

Comment: You are curling to a https site, so you need to look at the parameters you are required to pass to curl to make it work with https

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you :)